# How do I return the IDENTITY for an inserted record from a stored Proecedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am adding data to my database, but would like to retrieve the UnitID that is Auto generated.

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connections)) 
{ 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ContactInfo_Add", connect); 
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", name)); 
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("address", address)); 
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Product", name)); 
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Quantity", address)); 
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DueDate", city)); 
connect.Open(); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Contact_Add] 
@name varchar(40), 
@address varchar(60), 
@Product varchar(40), 
@Quantity varchar(5), 
@DueDate datetime 
AS  
BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON; 

 INSERT INTO DBO.PERSON 
 (Name, Address) VALUES (@name, @address) 
 INSERT INTO DBO.PRODUCT_DATA 
 (PersonID, Product, Quantity, DueDate) VALUES (@Product, @Quantity, @DueDate) 
END
```

Comment: Both SQL Server and MySQL?   Looks like SQL Server syntax to me . . .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an output parameter to your procedure:

```
@new_id int output
```

and after the insert statement, assign it value:

```
set @new_id = scope_identity()
```

The add it to your calling code:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@new_id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

and retrieve the value:

```
int newId = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@new_id"].Value);
```

Comment: Racing for rep points on SO has done more for my typing skills than (many) years of previous practice :)

Comment: sorry - error in my code - should be  Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@new_id"].Value); - answer edited

Answer (score 3):

With MSSQL its safer to use:

```
SET @AN_INT_OUTPUT_PARAM = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Or simply

```
RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 2):

in the Stored procedure Add in the end

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

in the C#
define an integer outside using and assign it inside using

```
int UnitID;

UnitID = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: if you're using SQL, I think you dont even need to create a new output parameter...just doing a SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() at the end of the sproc, and whatever you get from ExecuteScalar() in ADO.NET will be the new identity.

Answer (score 0):

Search Books Online for OUTPUT clause if you have SQL server 2008. This is the best method.